# Watson Visual Recognition: Curl command "url: (6) Could not resolve host: POST; Host not found"

Tags: curl, nginx, visual-recognition

Im wondering why a majority of the classes I wanted to include in my classifier are not made when I create a classifier?

I used the following code to train my classifier (using curl -k instead of curl -x) but not all of the classes I wanted to create were shown in the output/response:

input:

```
curl.exe -k POST -F "Hairline Cracking
Severe_positive_examples=@HairLineCracking_Severe.zip" -F "Durability 
Cracking_positive_examples=@DCracking.zip" -F 
"Scaling_positive_example=@Scaling.zip" -F "Pop 
Outs_positive_example=@PopOuts.zip" -F "Offset 
Cracking_positive_example=@OffsetCracking.zip" -F "Map 
Cracking_positive_example=@MapCracking.zip" -F "Hairline 
Cracking_positive_example=@HairLineCracking.zip" -F 
"negative_examples=@NotConcrete.zip" -F "name=concreteIssues" 
"https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classifiers?
api_key={apikey}=2017-05-20"
```

output:

```
url: (6) Could not resolve host: GET; Host not found

"classifier_id": "concreteIssues_580100916",
    "name": "concreteIssues",
"owner": "6217d8a0-8995-4b94-9e96-bfacd090bfcb",
"status": "training",
"created": "2017-01-11T09:17:09.558Z",
"classes": [
    {"class": "Hairline Cracking Severe"},
    {"class": "Durability Cracking"}
]
```

Then, I tried updating the classifier by adding the remaining classes which weren't shown in the response, but it responded with a 413 Request Entity Too Large

(Note: all my .zips are less then 3mb so its not an issue of the zip file being too large)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question.  There are a few issues with the code as posted.

From your title, the error `“url: (6) Could not resolve host: POST; Host not found”` is coming from curl - on the client.  It means it tried to interpret the string `POST` as a URL, which it is not.

You mentioned using -k instead of -x.  The -k option tells curl to allow insecure certificates, which I don't think you want here.  You should remove the -k and the string `POST`.  Using the -F options implies POST.

Also, the part of the string "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classifiers?
api_key={apikey}=2017-05-20" appears to be missing the string "version" before the `=2017-05-20` part.  I assume that is a typo.

Now, on to the issue of why some classes do not appear, such as "Scaling" in your example.  Their is no obvious problem with your command that I see. However, this can happen if there are fewer than the minimum 10 positive required examples in the Scaling.zip file.   Is that possible?

About retraining and receiving the 413 error code - this can happen if you have more than about 100 training images total, due to a timeout internally.  This is a known issue - described in the July 5th release notes.  https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/visual-recognition/releasenotes.shtml

However, the good news is that although you may get this error message, the retraining process will most likely continue in the background and succeed.  You should follow this workflow - and not submit additional retraining requests for the same classifier until the first one completes, successfully or not:

So for retraining, the workaround workflow is to:

1. note the value of the `retrained` timestamp (if any) from GET /classifiers/{cid}  This is the time it was last successfully retrained.
2. start a single retrain request. Submitting retrain requests in parallel for a single classifier can cause undefined results.  VR tries to bar this, but there is a race condition as to which one is "first".
3. ignore a 413 error or 500 error from this call
4. wait 1 second per training image (new and previous / original images)
5. start polling GET /classifiers/{cid}  for the most accurate status
6. Check if the `retrained` timestamp has been updated.  This indicates success and you can repeat this process to add more images if desired.
7. If  the status is `ready` but the `retrained` timestamp is the same as from step 1, it means the retrain failed and the classifier rolled back to the state at step 1.  There will probably be an `explanation` field added to the classifier description now.
8. If, after waiting and polling for 10 seconds per training image, the status is still `retraining` and the `retrained` timestamp is not updated, it means a failure very likely occurred.  Using the classifier to /classify should have the same results as before the retrain request.